# Как по массиву точек линии определить на что похожа фигура

Tags: c#, алгоритм

Есть прямая из массива точек

```
List<Point> listP;
```

Как дать фигуре, в которую складывается эта линия определение из 4 типов. 
Причем чтобы можно было из неведомо чего(картинка 2 - замкнутость есть, но больше незамкнутости), определить в процентном содержании к какому-нибудь из этих типов(в случае картинки 2 к типу 2 соответственно).

Любую информацию, которая пришла вам в голову, напишите, пожалуйста.

Типы:

1. Округлости не замкнуто

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Острые углы не замкнуто:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Округлая замкнутость.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

4. Острая замкнутость.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: тут нужны нейросети с дрессировкой

Comment: @carcinogen75 боялся, что такое предложат :( Неумею это точно. Подозреваю, что возможно как-то по количеству пересечений, площади фигур, и нахождению острых углов сделать. Например брать в расчет пересечения на расстоянии больше стольки-то, измерять угл...

Comment: @Сергей слишком муторно

Comment: @carcinogen75 возможно-ли написать свою небольшую нейросеть с весами, входами, выходами для конкретной задачи без использования фраймворка?(Я очень неосведомлен в этом вопросе, простите)

Comment: @Сергей , я бы не стал браться за это дело, если совсем с темой не знаком. Либо изучать серьёзно тему, либо попытаться найти альтернативный способ (фреймворки не помогут, если про нейросети совсем не знаете).

Comment: @zcorvid , Понятно, спасибо. Ну разобраться можно, тем более задача для души и никак не обязывает, но люди снизу тоже дали ценные указания и я почти уверен, что возможно обойтись эврестическими условиями)

Comment: если картинки будут ровными и красивыми как привели в пример ниже - то можно без нейросетей, если же будут кривыми, нарисованными рукой человека - то будет проблематично. Если будете решать подходом через нейросети - обязательно возмите готовую библиотеку с нормальной документацией - не стоит изобретать велосипед - тема довольно сложная, но с использованием популярных библиотек решится относительно просто. В любом случае на будущее сильно пригодиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это как же у вас интересно определяется наличие не замкнутости/замкнутости точек? Даже если вы от второй к первой, от третей ко второй чертите линию - то почему вы в одних случаях то замыкаете последнюю точку на первую, то нет? И вас устраивает, определение замкнутости как "последняя точка совпадает с первой"?

А если устраивает - то не хотите соединять отрезки и определять есть ли [пересечения отрезков](https://habr.com/post/267037/)? (гуглим [алгоритм Бентли - Оттмана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8_%E2%80%94_%D0%9E%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0))

Также насколько я знаю, по набору точек можно пробовать определить, является фигура [выпуклой](http://mirznanii.com/a/313582/vypuklye-figury) ([алгоритм Грехема](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%93%D1%80%D1%8D%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0), [построение минимально выпуклых оболочек](https://habr.com/post/144921/))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: думаю, что замкнутая фигура имеет внутри площадь больше 50% от всего намулеванного. Сейчас почитаю, всё что вы написали, спасибо)

Comment: Так и сделал, главное свойство замкнутости взял - что близко к точке начала. Острые углы померил в момент когда рисуется фигура, по последним 3.

Answer (score 1):

Судя по условию, есть два свойства - замкнутость и скругленность (острость).

Замкнутость определить легко, для этого считаем расстояние между первой и последней точками, и если оно меньше определённого порога, то считаем, что фигура замкнутая (порог можно подбирать по-разному, можно его положить равным чем-то константному, например 1e-4, а можно выбирать исходя и, например, диаметра вашей кривой, то есть брать его, допустим, 0.01 умножить на максимальное попарное расстояние между точками списка).

Со скруглённостью сложнее. Тем более, что могут быть скруглённые участки и угловатые. Тут предлагаю попробовать для каждой точки считать угол между выходящими из неё отрезками (на предыдущую и на следующую точку), если угол меньше определённого порога (допустим, меньше, чем 135 градусов), то угол считается "острием". Далее, смотрите, если "остриёв" у вас больше, чем, например, 30% точек, то, считаете что кривая острая, иначе округлая.

Это только идея, чтобы её довести до ума, придётся пошаманить, добавить какие-то разумные эвристики оценки, исходя из специфики конкретной задачи. Ну или же, если совсем серьёзно подходить, запускать нейросеть, которая все вышеизложенные построения (и даже больше) выследит сама из экспериментальных данных.

Comment: тоже отличное условие замкнутости.