# Залить часть геометрической фигуры

Tags: c#, winforms, графика, рисование

Нужна помощь коллективного разума на тему: как залить часть произвольной замкнутой геометрической фигуры?

Usecase:

1. Пользователь рисует фигуру (эллипс/прямоугольник/замкнутый многоугольник)
2. Пользователь вводит процент, насколько фигура заполнена (0-100)
3. Мы делаем `.Fill()` куска фигуры

Зачем это нужно: пользователю скажем, что это вид сбоку на какие-то ёмкости. Ёмкости могут быть не только прямоугольные/круглые, но и сложного сечения, отсюда и проблема.

Получить площадь замкнутого многоугольника я могу, как и вычислить условные 25% от неё. А вот дальше-то что? Примем, что у нас многоугольник выпуклый, с одним "дном". Как на картинке.

Есть мысль идти тупо по точкам внутри контура, снизу вверх и влево-вправо, пока количество залитых пикселей не будет равно 25% от площади, но на большом поле это займёт кучу времени. А `Paint()` вызывается довольно часто.

Ниже пример, как если-бы пользователь нарисовал фигуру и ввёл 25% заполненности (в реале заливка будет снизу вверх, я в Paint нарисовал некорректно, но смысл не меняется)

Работаю в C# WinForms .net 3.5

[image]

Comment: .NET 3.5 устарел, причем настолько, насколько вообще непозволительно (ему 12 лет!). Перейдите на 4.7.2. Единственное, что вы потеряете - поддержку Windows XP. Visual Studio тоже поставьте 2019.

Comment: По поводу основного вопроса, пока сложно понять, что происходит. Есть ли более конкретный воспроизводимый пример с вашими попытками это реализовать? Вообще отрисовку можно выполнять на [`WritableBitmap`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap?view=netframework-4.8), а затем выводить на экран готовое.

Comment: Как посчитать площадь полигона (не знаю, насколько это валидно), показано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16281192/12888024). Но если в лоб решать, то можно сделать трассировку границ заливки (внутренний контур) и посчитать расстояние между всеми соседними горизонтальными пикселями, включая сами точки. Сумма расстояний и будет - общее количество пикселей, которое можно будет поделить на 4, или на что-нибудь еще.

Comment: у многоугольника есть грань которая считается полом?

Comment: У вас графика растровая или векторная? Если растровая, то я бы держал картинку в памяти в виде набора байт, и перерисовывал форму на каждое изменение. Все расчеты и обновления делал бы в байтах в памяти, а потом эти байты просто накатывал на картинку целиком. Это не только позволит вам быстрее рендерить, но и отвяжет ваши алгоритмы от винформс, вы их хоть в консоли тестировать сможете.

Comment: 1) Был-бы я Product Owner'ом взял бы 4.5+
2) Я пока кроме пробежки по точкам ничего не родил. Кода, увы, нет и здесь я его не ожидаю - хотя-бы мозговой штурм(
3) Грань, которая считается полом, есть и она будет одна (ёмкость в виде буквы П не предвидится)
4) Рисуем на форме переопределив OnPaint. На панели уже десятки и сотни объектов, которые теперь нужно ещё и хитро заливать

Миграция/начинать проект заново не вариант - это адское legacy(

Comment: Ок, спасибо, что не .NET Framework 2.0 + Windows 98.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Общего алгоритма не знаю, но знаю, что для [выпуклых фигур](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/889055/213987) вполне достаточно обойти все строки изображения по порядку снизу вверх и заливать в цикле горизонтальные строчки.

Для каждой строчки заливаем цветом "серёдку" между двумя точками фигуры - крайней слева и крайней справа):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Поскольку мы договорились, что фигура выпуклая, то точек будет либо две, либо (в вырожденном случае) одна.

В процессе считаем нужный процентаж от высоты фигуры, чтобы остановиться вовремя.

Если фигура начинается не с самого низа картинки (а это вероятно так будет), то сначала нужно досчитать до первой горизонтальной линии

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(как вариант это может быть точка):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И только после этого начинать заливать.

> Есть мысль идти тупо по точкам внутри контура ... но на большом поле это займёт кучу времени.

Чертите не точками, а сразу горизонтальными линиями.